# DataGrid Template Column binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid that Auto Generates it's columns.

In Code i implement The AutoGeneratingColumn Event, to set a certain template for my Translation Datatype:

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyType == typeof(Translation)){
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["LanguageTemplate"];
            e.Column = templateColumn;
        }

    }
```

DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LanguageTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name.ActualTranslation}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="{lex:LocImage en}" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Name.HasCurrentLanguage, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, ConverterParameter=true}" ></Image>
        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Now a problem occured: The TextBlock is bound to Name Property. That works fine if the object to be displayed has a Name Property. But if i have Translation properties that are not named "Name" obviously no data is shown. How would i bind correctly to cover all Translation Items.

Comment: Could you also post the Translation-Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `DataTemplateSelector` where can choose the right `DataTemplate` for your current Translation class and add it to your `TextBlock.Text` binding. See [more](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Comment: I don't think it solves my problem. I can't create a DataTemplate for all possible Names, so the goal is to stick to 1 DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like a one way binding, do a simple binding with converter :

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource your_converter}}" ...
```

and implement your logic in the converter. It's the simpliest way if you have inconsistent ViewModels you want to bind on.